# How to upload file using multipart form data in nativescript?

Tags: javascript, file, file-upload, nativescript

I need to upload files along with other data from a Nativescript app. Here is what I am doing:

```
const data = new FormData();
data.append('name', 'Some Name');
data.append('profile_picture', profilePic);
```

Here profile pic is a [nativescript File object](http://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_file_system_.file.html). It does not seem to work as expected. It is sent to server as "[object object]".

How to do upload the file in form data?

Comment: Have your tried this? http://nativescript.github.io/nativescript-background-http/

Comment: Yes, it only allows to upload files directly as octet stream. Not as part of formdata.

Comment: If you want to send it as a form data, you could encode your picture in base64

Comment: That's fine for picture, but elsewhere I need to send video as well. base64 may not be the best way.

Answer (score 4):

Since January https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http supports multipart uploads, too.

Example:

```
var request = {
    url: url,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "File-Name": name
    },
    description: description
};

var params = [{name: "test", value: "value"}, {name:"fileToUpload", filename: file, mimeType: 'image/jpeg'}];
task = session.multipartUpload(params, request);
```

Comment: How would you upload multiple files?

Answer (score 2):

Binary support should be coming in NativeScript `v6.3`.  See [this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/7707).  You should then no longer need to use `nativescript-background-http`.  You can see my full write-up [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/7632).